# eclipse modify imported project files

Tags: python, eclipse, ide

I have used the "import existing project" option to import an existing project into workspace. However, eclipse actually makes copies of the original files and create a new project.

So, if I made a change on a file. It only affect on the copied file in workspace. The original file is untouched.

My question is how do I make my modification affected on the original files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Import Existing Projects into Workspace' wizard has a 'Copy projects into workspace' check box on the first page. Unchecking this option will make Eclipse work on the original files.